# Filter currency not working after upgrade

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've just upgraded to vue.js version 2. However after upgrading to vue.js version 2 my currency filter isn't working anymore. it throws a error on console.

```
<span class="amount">{{ amount | currency '£' }</span>
```

Console erro

> Failed to resolve filter: currency '£'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built in Text filters has been removed in vue.js version-2.

Replacing the currency Filter

> `'£' + price.toFixed(2)`

Reference

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-currency-Filter

Comment: Thanks! it fixed the issue but the filter was more convenient.